# Can I pass variables in hyperlink without using URL in PHP for use in a Table

Tags: php, html, mysql, url, html-table

Have looked, but have not found a simple solution. I am familiar with passing PHP URL data in hyperlinks, but I am looking to find a way to not see the data in the URL for security reasons. In the example

There are tables being used that include the user's name. The user's ID is not being shown in the table, but we have the data at the time because we are reading a MySql database to fill in the table. We want to show the user's name in a hyperlink in the table (which we can do easily), but we want to pass the user's ID to the next page without showing it in the URL.

Currently we are using the URL / GET in the following page like the code below:

**echo '<a href="/customer/?user='.$row["user_id"]">'.$row["user_name"].'**

But this produces a url that is "/customer/?user=123". We are trying to not show the User's ID, and yet pass the information to the next page. We could do this using $_SESSION['X'] variables or $_POST['X'] variables in a < form >. But I'm trying to be able to do it inside a table as opposed to a < form >. I'm thinking maybe something like ... onselect=$_SESSION['userID']=$row["user_id"] ... but I can't seem to get it to work?

Or maybe some form of:

**<a href="< ?PHP $_SESSION['userID']=$row["user_id"] ?>/customer/>'.$row["user_name"].'**

OR

**<a href='javascript: ('set $_SESSION variable / goto URL');'>Execute JavaScript**

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm sure passing table URL's securely must be out there somewhere, but I have not been able to find it 8-(

Comment: Possible for you to encode?

Comment: Why not pass the username instead and validate it on the receiving end? This seems it would look cleaner in my opinion

Comment: You could encode the data using a php based encoding system then send it over the url as encoded data, then decode the data on the other page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to send the user_id over HTTP without it being visible somehow. You could obscure it by having a  inside of each table row. You could even have a javascript object that correlates each user name with the user_id, then build a form using javascript and call on the PHP page that way. But regardless, if you send the user_id to the client, no matter how you obscure it,  a savvy user will be able to obtain it. Obscurity is no security as they say.

The most secure thing you can do is never send the client the user_id. Just have the target page look up the user id with each call. Or the session variable as you suggested.

Comment: The intention is to not send anything to the client side at all. But I can't figure out how to send the user id to the new page. Session or POST would be best ... But I can't figure out how to send the specific Session variable when the hyperlink is clicked

Comment: I think you misunderstand how HTTP requests and sessions work. When a user clicks a link, they are sending information back to the server. So whether it's a GET or a POST request, the information for doing so resides on the client computer. Sessions work behind the scenes to prevent sending sensitive data to the client. If you have have session_start() in your server code, and do something like $_SESSION['this_id'] = 12, then the server will know that for that user $_SESSION['this_is'] will return 12. You don't have to send the server any session variables.

Comment: Thanks, but I understand that. Im trying to basically find a way to use SESSION or POST (w/o a form). I'd prefer NOT to send any sensitive data to the client at all. But it seems from the responses that I can only use encoded URLs to with a hyperlink, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The following does not get into security and security is very important. I would suggest using `$_POST` as it is much more secure than `$_GET`.

If you are using `$_GET`, consider the following code...

Say you have php page ***somepage.php*** and it gathers form info then you can encode it and send the encoded string across that URL. The following is very basic and I would suggest looking into further hashing techniques to secure your data further should you send it over a URL.

You have a user `$user='user1@someusersaccount.com'`

==> ***somepage.php***

```php
$username = $_POST['username'];

$param = base64_encode($userName);

$url = 'users.php?user="'.$param;

header("Location: $url");
```

The url is sent `users.php?user="dXNlcjFAc29tZXVzZXJzYWNjb3VudC5jb20`

Then use `$_GET['user']` and decode the encoded message on the other page

==> ***users.php***

```php
$output = '';
// if the GET global variable is set 'user' the set $output to the decoded string
if(isset($_GET['user'] ) ){
    $user = $_GET['user'];
    $output = base64_decode($user);
}

echo output;
```

The following decoded echo would show `user1@someusersaccount.com` should the global get array 'user' be set.